# So "would like" should be used in specific situations & "like" in general situations, right?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

While discussing the benefits of fruits in a class, a Filipino teacher said:

"*In general, fruits are very good for health. Some people would like to eat bananas & some would like to eat oranges.*"

I would say the Filipino teacher was wrong. But I am not so sure.

I think "**would like**" should be used in specific situations & "**like**" in general situations.

You often eat oranges. You like oranges the most. So you said "**I like oranges**" (I like it most of the time)

But in a specific situation:

For example, you are currently in your friend's home. Your friend brought a banana & an orange to you. And you said "**I would like to eat bananas**". You could also say this to your friend: "**Generally, I like oranges, but now I would like to eat bananas**"

So "**would like**" should be used in specific situations & "**like**" in general situations, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trKQm1ZXmQ0)

"**like**" for general preference

"**Would like**" for specific & at the moment preference

Answer (score 0):

To be simple, *"I would like"* is a polite way to say *"I want"*.

In your example

> In general, fruits are very good for health. Some people would like to eat bananas & some would like to eat oranges.(*This simply means some people want to eat bananas some people want to eat orange.*)

*Would like* can also be used for an offer or to accept a request. For instance,

> A: *Would* you *like* to eat oranges?
>      B: Yes, *I'd like* to!

You use like *"like"* to express that you enjoy or love something.

> I like oranges

Means you enjoy eating oranges